# C++ iterate though list of obj and change/modify value

Tags: c++

I have a class Person which has a string variable for name, and int variable for age.

In main function, I created two people, then add two people to list of People, then pass to a function to update the age:

```
Person p1 = Person("personA", 4) // personA is 4 years old
Person p2 = Person("personB", 6) // personB is 6 years old

list<Person> list1;   // create a list of Person 
list1.push_back(p1);  // push personA to list
list1.push_back(p2);  // push perosnB to list

updateAge(list1); // pass to another function to update age
```

My question is how you iterate through every items in the list and update the age? I'm thinking of creating the pointer (not sure though). Can anyone show me any hint?

Comment: How do you want to update the age? What is the logic?

Comment: `std::for_each(list1.begin(), list1.end(), [](Person& p) { p.age++; });`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like so:

```
void updateAge(list<Person> & people)
{
    for (list<Person>::iterator i = people.begin(); i != people.end(); ++i) {
        i->age(i->age() + 1);
    }
}
```

This assumes you would have something like the following getter and setter members on `Person`:

```
int age() const;
void age(int);
```

You can access any members of the current `Person` object using the `i->` prefix within the `for` loop.  So if you have a `public: int age;` member instead, you could do this:

```
++(i->age);
```

Note that the parameter to the example function I've written is a `list<Person> &` (reference to a list) as opposed to a `list<Person>` (a by-value list).  If you don't make the parameter a reference then the list (and all of the `Person` objects it contains!) will be *copied* when you call the function, and the function will receive that copy, which is independent of the original list.  When the function returns, the copied list and its contents will be destroyed and any modifications made to the copied list will be lost.

Passing by reference (as is done in my example function) means that the `people` parameter and the `list1` variable you have in your code would refer to *the same list* so changes made to one variable can be observed through the other variable.

Comment: awesome. I didn't pass as a reference. That's why after I update it and return to main function. it's doesnt change

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is:

```
for ( auto &person : people )
    ++person.age;
```

Another option besides those already posted is to make a function to do the job for one person, and then use standard algorithms to apply that to the whole list.

Doing it this way, you can change your `list` to be a different container and then you don't have to change any of the other code. Or you can do it on just part of the list at once, and so on.

```
void update_age(Person &p)
{
    ++p.age;
}

// ... in another function
    std::for_each( people.begin(), people.end(), update_age );
```